# How to get an element of a LinkedHashMap

Tags: android, kotlin, compiler-errors, linkedhashmap

Hi I have this LinkedHashMap

```
{0={Question=What is Gravity?, Answer=Whatever}, 1={Question=What is Motion?, Answer=Whatever}}
```

displayed by the following code=

```
linkedHashMapForLessonContent = (intent.getSerializableExtra(tags?.LESSON_MAP_TAG_NAME) as WrapperSerializer<LinkedHashMap<String, Any>>).get() as LinkedHashMap<String, Any>
Log.e("helloworld", linkedHashMapForLessonContent!!.toString())
```

until then it works perfectly, then I want to access the 0 value with the following code=

```
val d = linkedHashMapForLessonContent!!["0"] as LinkedHashMap<String, Any>
```

which gives me an error and I do not know why, what I want to get is the Question value, I've been stuck for hours in that same problem so if someone can help me I would be so thankful :)

Thank you and have a good coding :)

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: `val d = (linkedHashMapForLessonContent as LinkedHashMap<String, Any>)["0"]`

Comment: an error that says runtime error

Comment: not working :( but thank you

Comment: Now working, thank you :)